# Can not install passport on my laravel project

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I ran **php artisan passport:install** also **php artisan passport:install --force** but nothing works I get the same error/issue. And there is nothing added to my users table in the database.

Error:

```
Encryption keys generated successfully.

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `oauth_clients` (`user_id`, `name`, `secret`, `provider`, `redirect`, `personal_access_client`, `password_client`, `revoked`, `id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, Laravel Personal Access Client, xDElm83oBuzriqEs9ItvSymxWT8QGEliQBS8VFV8, ?, http://localhost, 1, 0, 0, 94a9e5f4-6e5c-42d4-a6dc-f2e53042edb4, 2021-10-18 16:24:43, 2021-10-18 16:24:43))

  at C:\Users\Viruss\Desktop\meme-library-crud\crud-meme-app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:703
    699▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    700▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    701▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    702▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 703▕             throw new QueryException(
    704▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    705▕             );
    706▕         }
    707▕     }

  1   C:\Users\Viruss\Desktop\meme-library-crud\crud-meme-app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:492
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'id' at row 1")

  2   C:\Users\Viruss\Desktop\meme-library-crud\crud-meme-app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:492
      PDOStatement::execute()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this error couldn't be resolved so I made a new laravel project and run everything from the beginning which helped me avoid this error again ...